# Advice for using Google AdSense

Tags: google, google-adsense, jquery, ajax

The banners on my website are generated by `$.ajax()` call to the server after the page load is complete (`$(window).load()` event).

I want to to integrate ads from google to fill in empty banners when there is no active campaign associated to them.

I know that using ajax to place the AdSense code after the page load is complete is a  violation of the [AdSense Program Policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48182).

Is it legal (in terms of that program politics) to place the AsSence code as a default in all the banners on my website, and after the ajax request, remove unnecessary banners and replace them with banners from my own advertising management system?

I couldn't find a straight answer to this issue, and I don't want to change the logic of my CMS to be able to use google adsense in my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this would be allowed. Google is pretty strict on how their ads are used, and doing what you mentioned would cause your ad impressions to increase even though the ad wouldn't be seen by your site visitors because it would be replaced. This could get your account banned.